# What is 'green green' weather?

Tags: esa, ariane

During the today (24/08/16) launch of Ariane 5, Stéphane Israël (chairman & CEO) tells that all conditions are good, including a *green green weather*.

Is it a shortcut for *no wind, no rain*, or something like that ?

[Link to the youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74_8VIurLm8#t=8m5s)

Comment: Guessing, but in the US we say *weather is GO, forecast GO*, meaning OK right now, and predicted to be OK (meet all launch weather criteria) for the launch window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. During Arianespace launch broadcasts, they sometimes show a list of launch conditions. This is a list of about 15 items shown in red or green. If all are green, the launch is proceeded with. An item shown in red means a delay or scrub.
This is similar to the voice poll NASA uses (where each department head says 'Go' or 'No go' a few minutes before launch).

Example from a Vega launch using a similar system:
[image: Vega launch poll]